# getting error the operation 'alter table add index' is not supported with memory optimized tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am working with sql server, I need to add index for the column, when adding index it gives me error `the operation 'alter table add index' is not supported with memory optimized tables.`, can anyone please tell me how can i resolve this issue ? Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE "tb_Episode" (
    "ID" INT NOT NULL,
    "EpDataID" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "UploadID" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "CustID" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "BranchID" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Branch" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "LastName" VARCHAR(19) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "FirstName" VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "Middle" VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "MRN" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "MedicareNbr" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "EpStart" DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "EpEnd" DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "SOCDate" DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "DOB" DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "SysBranch" VARCHAR(24) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "PhyLastName" VARCHAR(24) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "PhyFirstName" VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "SNVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "PTVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "OTVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "HHAVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "MSWVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "STVisits" INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
;
```

Comment: Are you working with memory optimized tables?

Comment: I am not aware with that, i am new with sql server,I checked it is not memory optimized table, can you please tell me how can i convert it in memory optimized table ?

Comment: Why do u want to convert it to `memory optimized` table , any specific reason for that. More resource on : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables

Comment: If it is not a memory optimised table, then you need to use `CREATE INDEX ...` rather than `ALTER TABLE... ADD INDEX` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql

Comment: @BHouse i need to add indexing so

Comment: Who created the table?  Was it you, an application, another person?  Give some background as to why you're using this table, what you want to do to the table, etc, etc.

Comment: @MatBailie there are lakh of records, so getting time to fetch the record, i need to apply indexing on it, but not able to add

Comment: @Nikul Please give us some background, you also have to read implications of converting into `memory optimized tables`. You can add indexes or constraints before converting them into 'memory optimized tables`. Further, you should also have thought about maintaining them in a bigger picture as long term goal, compatibility, sustainability etc..

Comment: See this for indexing memory optimized tables. 
 The syntax is a bit different than with "regular" tables. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/indexes-for-memory-optimized-tables

Comment: @BHouse is this query work for indexing ? CREATE  INDEX SOC
ON tb_Episode(SOC);

Comment: @nikul yes it will .but not for `memory optimized` tables

Comment: @Nikul Did ***you*** create the table, or did ***someone else*** create the table?  You seem to be uncertain about important details, which makes me think you didn't create it.  If you didn't create it, don't mess about with it...

Comment: @BHouse thanks for help

Comment: @MatBailie i have added my table structure in my question, can you tell me how can i speed up to get the data

Comment: @Nikul If that's the full table DDL, then it does not appear to be a memory optimised table.  Please include the full `ALTER TABLE` your attempting too.

Comment: @Nikul, also add the tag specific for the SQL Server version you are using.

Comment: @DanGuzman its sql version is : Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 10):

Use `CREATE INDEX` statement instead of `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX`.

```
CREATE INDEX Index_Name
ON Table_Name (Column_Name)
```

Explanation:

The error message is a bit deceiving. It's just the wrong syntax you're using.

Also, your table does not appear to be memory optimized because I don't see MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON in your create table statement.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It's the correct answer. Nothing to do with memory optimised tables, just wrong syntax.